# move text from BreadCrumb to the left

Tags: css, breadcrumbs

I want to move the text "Home" from the BreadCrumb "Search" to the left, so that it is over the Sidebar.

You can see it being on the right [in this example](http://ntm.at/r0sa/).

When I type `text align: left` it only moves a few px to the left.
What's the right code?

Comment: Your entire <div id="header"> is positionned to right, you first need to change that or change your HTML code.

Comment: Thanks,  I moved the Header that it is right:1300px . Now is the full breadcrumb on the left, but i want to have the "searchform" on the right, and the "home"-Text in the position it is now.

Comment: Actually you have given limited width to your h2 tag under which you have written the HOME text, firstly you should take it in a div and then increase the width of that div.

Comment: Or give h2{width=950px; text-align:left;}

Comment: is this right?.entry h2 {
width=950px; 
text-align:left
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
text-transform: uppercase;

Comment: because nothing is happening!

Comment: The link to the example is not working. Can you make it work?

Answer (score 0):

remove width from class ".BreadCrumb" or add '`float :left;`' should work

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but it changes nothing. I want to keep the searchform on the right, and only move the text "HOME" to the right. the changes are always for the WHOLE breadcrumb... when i delete the width, nothing changes. wenn i type float:left, nothing changes too. any other ideas?